# Kotlin - group elements by a key under some conditions with new value type

Tags: collections, kotlin, hashmap, mapping, flatmap

I'm trying to find a way to use Kotlin collection operation to do some logic that I'm going to explain:

Let's say type `Classroom` contains a list of `Student` as a field in it, `eg. classroom.getSudents()` returns a list of certain studends.

Now I have a list of mixed `Student` that I need to group by one of its fields say **major**, and the value of the resultant map to be `Classroom`.

So I need to convert `List<Student>` to `Map<Student.major, Classroom>`

Also at some cases of **major**, for example for all `major == chemistry`, I'll need to group by another criteria, say **firstname**, so the keys of major chemistry would be `major_firstname`

Here's an example, I have a list of `Student(major, firstname)`:

```
[
    Student("chemistry", "rafael"), 
    Student("physics", "adam"),
    Student("chemistry", "michael"),
    Student("math", "jack"),
    Student("chemistry", "rafael"),
    Student("biology", "kevin")
]
```

I need the result to be:

```
{
    "math" -> Classroom(Student("math", "jack")),
    "physics" -> Classroom(Student("physics", "adam")),
    "chemistry_michael" -> Classroom(Student("chemistry", "michael")),
    "chemistry_rafael" -> Classroom(Student("chemistry", "rafael"), Student("chemistry", "rafael")),
    "biology" -> Classroom(Student("biology", "kevin"))
}
```

I've tried `groupBy`, `flatMapTo` and `associateBy` but as far as I understand all of these doesn't group by a certain condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the mixture of those methods which you require. There are also other ways to achieve it, but here is one possible example using `groupBy` and `flatMap`:

```
val result = students.groupBy { it.major }
    .flatMap { (key, values) -> when (key) {
        "chemistry" -> values.map { it.firstname }
                             .distinct()
                             .map { firstname -> "chemistry_$firstname" to ClassRoom(values.filter { it.firstname == firstname }) }
        else -> listOf(key to ClassRoom(values))
    }
}.toMap()
```

Assuming the following data classes:

```
data class Student(val major: String, val firstname: String)
data class ClassRoom(val students : List<Student>)
```

If you also want a map with all students grouped by major, the following suffices:

```
val studentsPerMajor = students.groupBy { it.major }
                               .map { (major, values) -> major to ClassRoom(values) }
```

If you then rather want to continue working with that map instead of recalculating everything from the source, it's also possible, e.g. the following will then return your desired map based on the `studentsPerMajor`:

```
val result = studentsPerMajor.flatMap { (key, classroom) -> when (key) {
        "chemistry" -> classroom.students.map { it.firstname }
                                         .distinct()
                                         .map { firstname -> "chemistry_$firstname" to ClassRoom(classroom.students.filter { it.firstname == firstname }) }
        else -> listOf(key to classroom)
    }
}.toMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the 1st part as Roland posted an answer for the 2nd part (although I did not try it).  
Assuming your classes are:

```
class Student(val major: String, val firstName: String)

class Classroom(val studentList: MutableList<Student>) {
    fun getStudents(): MutableList<Student> {
        return studentList
    }
}
```

and with an initialization like:

```
val list = mutableListOf<Student>(
        Student("chemistry", "rafael"),
        Student("physics", "adam"),
        Student("chemistry", "michael"),
        Student("math", "jack"),
        Student("chemistry", "rafael"),
        Student("biology", "kevin"))

val classroom = Classroom(list)
val allStudents = classroom.getStudents()
```

you can have a result list:

```
val finalList: MutableList<Pair<String, Classroom>> = mutableListOf()

allStudents.map { it.major }.distinctBy { it }.forEach { major ->
    finalList.add(major to Classroom(allStudents.filter { it.major == major }.toMutableList()))
}
```

so by the below code:

```
finalList.forEach {
    println(it.first + "->")
    it.second.getStudents().forEach { println("    " + it.major + ", " + it.firstName) }
}
```

this will be printed:

```
chemistry->
    chemistry, rafael
    chemistry, michael
    chemistry, rafael
physics->
    physics, adam
math->
    math, jack
biology->
    biology, kevin
```